# Why did Lord Krishna die alone?

Tags: krishna, arjuna

It is believed that Krishna had several wives yet only eight of them were crowned queens. He also had exactly ten children from each of those queens, hence [eighty sons](https://iskcondwarka.org/blogs/krishna-facts-80-sons-lord-krishna/). With such a huge family he died alone in the woods, is there a message behind this?
Also where was Arjun his most trusted friend and follower?

Comment: If i am not wrong the story of Lord Krishna's death is mentioned in Mahabharata's 
Mausala Parva and Stri parva.It was a culmination of Gandhari's curse to the Yadava Clan.It was the part of Lord Krishna's Divine Leela to die alone and i dont think there was any special message involved in it.

Comment: Also acc to the story Lord Krishna died when the Hunter Jara pierced his foot with an arrow as he mistook it for a deer's mouth.(apparently Lord Krishna's life used to reside in it(read barbarika's story for this reference)).It is said that Jara was the reincarnation of Sugriva's brother Bali, whom Vishnu had killed from behind in his incarnation as Rama, so Jara was killing Krishna the way Rama had killed Vali.

Comment: Obviously As Lord Krisna had planned his death in such a manner,he kept all Pandavas as away from his as possible as they wouldn't have let him die.(As far as i know All Pandavas were at hastinapur at that time)

Comment: @Rāmachandra can you please provide a link to Barbarika's story, thanks

Comment: seems like Barbarika's story is just a folk tale and not a part of original story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well Krishna's death has some connections to Shri Ramchandra's boon to sugriv 's brother Bali

*Hanuman natak 5.57*

**शुद्धिर्भविष्यति पुरन्दरनन्दन!त्वं मामेव चेदहह!पातकिनं शयानं।
सौख्यार्थिनं निरपराधिनमाहनिष्यस्यस्मात्पुनर्जनजाविरहोऽस्तु मा मे।।**

Shri Ram says:- O son of Indra! If you will kill me when I would be in yognidra, who enjoys happiness and innocent (ie during krishna avtar), then my sin of killing you will be atoned.

Note:- shri Ram being a god call his act as sin is just symbol of politeness and humbleness.

Comment: Yes I remember this story, where Jambavatha a bear like god or avatar wants to kill Krishna but instead gets killed or surrenders since Krishna is a avatar of Lord Ram

Comment: If I'm not wrong..Is this the same scripture which was written by Hanumanji and then thrown into the water?

Comment: Yes, and it was dug out of sea by maharaja bhoj.

Answer (score 0):

Lord Krishna is embodiment of virtue. As a virtuous person he atoned for his sins of previous birth by dying in this way which is just like Newton's third law "To every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction". Since he killed vali by hiding, jara, the hunter also killed krishna by mistaking his foot to a pigeon sitting on a tree branch looking at his legs rested under the tree.